# Trying to pass an array to javascript from rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to pass an array back from a helper, and while it works for some part of my javascript, it doesn't work for the other half. For example, here's my helper:

```
def quick_stats_bar_chart
    names = []
    emails = []
    students = []
    results = []

    @exams.each do |exam|
        names << trim_exam_name(exam.name)
        emails << exam.exam_results
        student << exam.exam_results
        results << exam.exam_results
    end
    return [names, emails, students, results]
end
```

and here's my view in the javascript

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var barData = {
            labels: ["Random"],
            datasets: [
            {
                label: "Emails",
                backgroundColor: '#dedede',
                pointBorderColor: "#dedede",
                data: <%= quick_stats_bar_chart[1] %>
            },
            {
                label: "Students",
                backgroundColor: '#a3e1d4',
                pointBackgroundColor: "#a3e1d4",
                pointBorderColor: "#a3e1d4",
                data: <%= quick_stats_bar_chart[2] %>
            },
            {
                label: "Results",
                backgroundColor: '#b5b8cf',
                pointBackgroundColor: "#b5b8cf",
                pointBorderColor: "#b5b8cf",
                data: <%= quick_stats_bar_chart[3] %>
            }
            ]
        };

        var barOptions = {
            responsive: true
        };


        var ctx2 = document.getElementById("participationChart1").getContext("2d");
        new Chart(ctx2, {type: 'bar', data: barData, options:barOptions});
    });
```

The code `labels: ["Random"]` is where I have issues. If I leave it like this, it works, but I cannot use `<%= quick_stats_bar_chart[0] %>` because I get an error stating

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'

The `labels` option is supposed to take an array, so I'm not sure why the array isn't being passed and parsed correctly.

Any thoughts? Again, I can manually put in an array, but trying to call it from the helper gives me this error.

**Edit**

Here's what quick_stats_bar_chart[0] looks like:

```
[2] pry(#<#<Class:0x00007f0c99675370>>)> quick_stats_bar_chart[0]
=> ["Random.."]
[3] pry(#<#<Class:0x00007f0c99675370>>)> quick_stats_bar_chart[1]
=> [1]
```

It gives me an error on [0] but not [1].

Here's the FULL variable output:

```
[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x00007f0c99675370>>)> quick_stats_bar_chart
=> [["Random.."], [1], [1], [0]]
```

Here's with `raw`
[2] pry(#<#>)> raw(quick_stats_bar_chart[0])
=> "[\"Random..\"]"

Comment: Have you tried to debug what is inside `quick_stats_bar_chart` ?

Comment: Yep, When I place a `binding.pry` and look at quick_stats_bar_chart[0], it's an array, just like the one I provided manually and everything worked (manually that is)

Comment: Looks like it's not valid array for javascript code. Show what is inside that variable.

Comment: What's strange though is that the other ones are arrays too and they're being accepted just fine, except quick_stats_bar_chart[1], [2], and [3] are actually array containing integers, unlike [0] which is a string.

Comment: Your errors is clear, it's syntax error, so your array isnt valid.

Comment: Right. I'm not sure why. [1], [2], and [3] are arrays as well, except they're integer elements instead of string elements in the array.

Comment: show your array, just show what is inside variable please . Add `= debug(MY_AWESOME_ARRAY)` to your view and show the output please.

Comment: No output shows in the view. Same error occurred from what I see in the console. However, I updated my answer to what I'm seeing in the rails console when inspecting the variable in question. I added `= debug(<%= quick_stats_bar_chart[0]` so it appears as `labels: = debug(<%= quick_stats_bar_chart[0]`

Comment: Please show _full_ array, all values, not only at 0 and 1, *all values please*.

Comment: Updated post. Thanks.

Comment: add `<%= raw(quick_stats_bar_chart[0]) %>`. on the each `quick_stats_bar_chart` methods.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks a lot! Very interesting!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need marks a string as trusted safe. It will be inserted into HTML with no additional escaping performed. Use the [`raw()`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw) method for his.